# How to validate chess moves with a server? Winboard and Unity 2020.3

Tags: engines, rules, software, cheating, windows

I'm looking for advice on how to implement online chess move validation using a winboard chess engine. I am creating a mobile battle chess game in Unity 2020.3. Right now I have the possible moves for each player, castle rights, check status, etc being generated by an [open source C# chess engine](https://www.chessprogramming.org/NoraGrace).  I chose this engine because it's written in C# and the code could be directly included in my Unity Project. I successfully wrote my own code that connects this chess engine to a 3D battle chess game.

**How the game works** ([video preview](https://youtu.be/Hd-LO8a4Ut0)):

1. A piece is selected by the player clicking it with their mouse or tapping the screen.
2. The possible moves for the current board are calculated by the chess engine.
3. I use the possible move indexes to show possible move highlights.
4. When a player makes one of these possible moves,  the move is applied on the chess engine.
5. It becomes the other player's turn.

*I have some custom code to run player animations, based on the kind of move (ex. an attack animation runs when a piece is captured). I also show have screens that show when it's time for a promotion, a player is in check, or the game is over.*

I'd like to somehow make the process of calculating possible moves and applying moves to be done on a server.  My goal is to protect from players sending illegal moves to the board and breaking the game.

How would you recommend I approach this problem? This is the last thing I need to turn this game into an enjoyable online experience. I just lack the crucial skill of understanding how to make this game online.

Comment: Welcome to our community! Thank you for making the effort of asking this question but I don't think it's within the scope of our site. It doesn't look like a chess-related problem at all

Comment: What do you mean by validation? If you mean cheat detection, this is probably on-topic. If you mean legal move detection, it's a coding problem (and seems a trivial one: just generate the legal moves and check the proposed move is in that set...)